# .Net App has reference but is not being recognized in class

Tags: c#, .net, reference, .net-assembly

[Image showing that System.Net is in references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkDAM.png)

This is an older .net app running 4.5.1
I added the System.Net reference.
Closed/Restarted Visual Studio.
Unloaded/Loaded project.
Cleaned/Built/Rebuilt Project and Solution, but it still is missing the reference.

Unsure what to do next?

Added reference and removed reference to System.Net

csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Net.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Where do you add the reference to `System.Net`? Can you paste in the `.csproj` snippet where the reference is added

Comment: remove VS temp files maybe? delete `.vs` then try?

Comment: @Flydog57 added the reference